# Paypal refund api for paypal adaptive payments when sender is more than one?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have paypal adaptive payments enabled in my website. When customer buy any product from a third party seller then about 90% of the amount seller gets and about 10% amount is transferred to me. Bu in case customer wants refund for that product then it should return amount from both accounts which are primary receiver and secondary receiver. So how to do that using refund api. I want to use this php api but i think it is only for one receiver.

[Refund api](https://www.formget.com/paypal-refund-api/)

is there any other solution for this so payment will deduct from both the receiver primary and secondary ?

Comment: There's a particular `Refund` API for adaptive payments, what you're looking at is the `RefundTransaction` API which is for general merchant products (e.g. Express Checkout). See the answer below from @Zhao Samanta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/ ("Using the payment key to refund an entire payment" part ), you can call https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Refund API , The total amount from each receiver is refunded to the sender.

Comment: Should I have to pass the payment key to this url or have to create any form to do that ?

Comment: I have created a refund button in my e-commerce website, then should I pass the payment key to this url when I click on the button ?

Comment: pay-key value is obtained from the previous Pay api response. Yes, you should pass the payment key to this url

Comment: I created this code using documentation written in the link you shared

http://pastie.org/10884919

What should i have to change in this code ?

Comment: Can show me an example how to pass data to this url ?

Comment: You can refund the full amount (primary and secondary) despite the fact that you are the secondary receiver? Do you need 3rd party permissions on the primary receiver's account for this?